# O(c) Time complexity to read a few gigs text file

Tags: file-io, time-complexity, space-complexity

I've been tasked to solve a puzzle as follows:
Program an input parser (in C, Python, Java, or Go) that reads a file from standard input and
reads the data into a byte array (8-bit bytes). 
checks if the line has a unique set of byte values. If so, it should keep track of the line number Finally, it should print out the line numbers that have a unique set of byte values on each line.

-The program should run in an efficient manner and time – it should not reach big O(n^2)
complexity or worse. Try to see if you can do it in big O(n) time.
- The file should be read into a byte array (8-bit values) without exceeding memory.

I'm reading from the sample file I'm using which is 50MBfile ,
line by line and storing the line in a byte array
then calling a method `checkDuplicate(byte[] arr)` and pass the byte array
and then create a hashset and loop through the elements of the array and add them to the hashset and then return the size of the hashset.
Since hashsets don't allow duplicates back in the main i check if the returned size is equal to the array size to determine if it is unique or not to save the line number.

```
private  int checkDuplicate(byte[] arr) {
         HashSet<Byte> byteSet = new HashSet<Byte>();
         int size=0;
         for (byte e : arr){

                if (e != 0 && byteSet.add(e)) {}

                    size = byteSet.size();
            }

        return size;
    }
```

Can O(c) or O(n) be achieved? 
I'm getting O(n^2) so far and will handle memory exceptions later on when I reach O(n).

also, would solving the problem in python reduce the time/space complexity?

Comment: it is not possible to read an entire `N` byte file in better than `O(N)`.

Comment: "would solving the problem in python reduce the time/space complexity?"  No.  The complexity of an algorithm is (should be) independent of the language that the algorithm is coded in.

Comment: You say _a unique set of byte values_, but your description of the algorithm suggests that you just mean unique byte values within the current line, which is different. (The two lines `AB` and `BA` contain the same (thus non-unique) _set_ of bytes, but the bytes within each line are unique.)

Comment: its actually a unique set of byte values per line. I could've misinterpreted it. but should I read nextByte untill I hit a \n ? that way the the time complexity would reduce from O(n^2) to O(n)? because I'd go through each byte not line by line then use another loop to through the bytes in the line?@Armali

Comment: are you saying you need to find the unique lines in a text-file? Like if the file contained "bar\nfoo\nbar\nquux\nbar\nbar" you want to return zero-based lines 1 and 3? if not what output are you looking for?